# Document Root https

Tags: apache, nginx, debian, vesta

У меня установлена VestCP. Она использует nginx+apache. Как прописать Document Root для http я знаю, а как прописать для https? OS - Debian 8

Comment: синтаксис директив documentroot программы apache и root программы nginx никак не зависит от протокола.

Comment: не совсем понял. у имею ввиду, что я прописал document root /public_html/public, но если открывать через https - то открывается просто /public_html

Comment: совет: вероятность получить квалифицированную консультацию по программам nginx и/или apache значительно выше, нежели по программам *controlpanel, потому **новичкам** имеет смысл не тратить своё время на эти самые программы *controlpanel.